# Can I implement kaldi-pytorch on windows?

Tags: pytorch, named-entity-recognition, kaldi

kaldi can only be used on windows via VM configuration (fedora 29 for example) , which massively consumes ressources of computations and late working flow . is there any other suitable way to configure and implement kaldi-pytorch on windows10 ? thanks

Comment: Use [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/alphacep/kaldi-ru).<br>
You can install docker on windows with [this instruction](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/).

Answer (score 0):

It is hopeless to do modern speech research on Windows, nobody uses it. Use Linux, everything will be smooth.